# firefox installation using chef with options

Tags: firefox, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, knife

from the chef supermarket i have installed mozilla-firefox and there is no Issue while doing it, I used the **knife** command and downloaded the mozila-firefox from the chef supermarket

```
knife cookbook site download mozilla-firefox
```

How can i customze the above cookbook so that i can add option in like

```
Installed Mozilla Firefox with the any options like
```

1. Disable Crash Reporter
2. Block popup windows

Answer (score 0):

I did a [fork](https://github.com/jcortejoso/chef-mozilla-firefox) of the cookbook to illustrate the changes:

1. Disable Crash Reporter
   It can be disabled setting the environment variable `MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE=1`. I usually set them with a script in `/etc/profile.d/`. Check the branch [feature/crash-reporter](https://github.com/jcortejoso/chef-mozilla-firefox/tree/feature/crash-reporter) to see the details.
2. Block popup windows
   I haven't implemented it because I don't know how do you would do it. Probably it can be set using a [user.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file) file, but if you know I better way I can help with the chef part.